# AWS CodeBuild: Accessing CodeCommit repository in another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I have a CodeCommit repo in Account A, that I would like to use as a source provider for my CodeBuild project in Account B.

I have created a Role in Account A with full codecommit access to Account B. I am lost on how to proceed further with this.

How do I use this role that in Account A in my CodeBuild project that is in Account B?

Comment: https://towardsthecloud.com/aws-cross-account-assume-role-script
Does this help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I cannot do this directly with CodeBuild so I created a CodePipeline, CMK, and an artifact bucket with the necessary permissions for the source code to get uploaded to it first. I followed this blog post to do it through the console and CLI, and then created CF templates for later re-use.

https://prashant-48386.medium.com/cross-account-codepipeline-that-use-codecommit-from-another-aws-account-9d5ab4c892f6

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a [cross-account pipeline using AWS CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/cross-account.html), which accesses the repository from Account A from another account - typically that would your CI/CD account. The CI/CD account then usually also deploys again to other accounts such as Test, QA or Prod.

See this [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/) for a description on how this can be implemented. There is also a [GitHub example from AWS](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cross-account-cicd-pipeline), along with a [accompanying workshop](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/00bc829e-fd7c-4204-9da1-faea3cf8bd88/en-US), that guides you through the full process. Just note that the GitHub sample + workshop assume the repo to be in the same account as the pipeline, while the blog post and your scenario have the repo in a different account.